# Flash player is not working

Tags: flash

I installed flash for mozilla firefox, via ubuntu software center and via terminal.

I have mozilla, chromium and google chrome installed and flash content is not showed. For example I go to youtube and the flash player remains white as the background and nothing happen.

I want to use Google Chrome, so there I get `Could not load Shockwave flash`.

I searched some solutions and I found that I have to delete `~/.config/google-chrome/PepperFlash`. Some users succeded. But I still have this error.

I rebooted the system and now google chrome crashes frequently.

Comment: How did install flash?

Comment: usc -> flash for mozilla and then i removed it. And via terminal i do not remember the command. I am on mobile and the command was something like 'sudo apt-get --install flashplayer-free'

Comment: I removed flash from usc after i tested it in firefox, and it not worked

Comment: Angrry - you appear to have two accounts.  Please click the contact us link at the bottom of the page and ask for your two accounts to be merged.  Thanks.

Comment: you can try: sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras

Answer (score 1):

Try installing flash this way.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
```

Comment: should I reboot ?

Comment: No need, but it wouldn't hurt?

Comment: i will try that when i arrive home

Comment: From the question: "I want to use Google Chrome". The `flashplugin-installer` has no effect on Google Chrome with its built-in Pepper-Flash.

Comment: The OP also mentioned having Firefox, and Chromium.  To try to have one browser work is better than nothing.